# clazz.getAnnotation(Class annotationClass) is null with a custom ClassLoader

Tags: java

I'm trying to get an annotation from a custom ClassLoader but I'm having some trouble.

```
ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault(); 
Loader cl = new Loader(classPool); 
c = cl.loadClass(className); 
c.getAnnotation(Annotation.class)
```

is `null` but  `c.getAnnotations()` is not empty.

Comment: is annotated with others but this: Annotation...

Comment: c is a Class not a ClassLoader

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all these details, I couldn't use  `c.getAnnotation(cl.loadClass(Annotation.class.getName()))` because I send a generated class as parameter and another object of PowerMock  that retrieves the annotation like `element.getAnnotation(classAnnotation.class)`. In fact my goal is to add annotation at runtime to a class that has already been loaded, I have not been able to execute `c.toClass()` because it is already loaded, that's why i thought to create a custom class loader containing the same object with the new annotation.

Thanks a lot